# Plotly.js - Heatmap animation very flickery

Tags: javascript, plotly

I am trying to animate a heatmap using Plotly.js.

So far I have got:

```js
var rho = [];
for (var n = 0; n < 100; n++) {
  rho[n] = [];
  for (var l = 0; l < 100; l++) {
    rho[n][l] = n * l;
  }
}

var dummy = 1;

var data = [{
  z: rho,
  type: 'heatmap'
}];

function compute() {
  dummy++;
  for (n = 0; n < 100; n++) {
    for (l = 0; l < 100; l++) {
      data[0].z[n][l] = Math.sin(0.3 * (n * l - 0.05) + dummy);
    }
  }
}

Plotly.newPlot('graph', data);

function update() {
  compute();
  rho = data[0].z;
  Plotly.animate('graph', {
    data: [{
      z: rho,
      type: 'heatmap'
    }]
  }, {
    transition: {
      duration: 100
    },
    frame: {
      duration: 100,
      redraw: true
    }
  })
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph" style="position: relative; width: 600px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

However, **this code does not produce a smooth animation** due to flickering.

If I set the duration of the transition or the animation to 0 (as it is shown [here](https://plot.ly/javascript/animations/#animating-many-frames-quickly) ), it does not even display the heatmap plot.

Why is this happening?

How can I fix the flickering and obtain a smooth animation (with double buffering or something similar)?

Comment: I dont have any ploty knowledge but you are starting your animation multiple times. With a duration of `100` (ms I guess) which is defenitely slower than `requestAnimationFrame` calls. So in each `update` call you are restarting a new animation instead of just continuing the current.

Comment: Why do you say I'm starting the animation multiple times?

Comment: I think flicker is coming due to `redraw: true`. Even I don't have knowledge about Plotly, but redraw will clear the frame and redraw it. So for a brief instance, there will be a white screen.

Comment: If i set **redraw** to **false**, the heatmap is not rendered!

Comment: @PintoDoido beacause you call `Plotly.animate` each time in your `update` and `requestAnimationFrame` calls `update` mutliple times per second. Therefore you will have multiple animations running when `update` is called before the previous animation is finished.

Comment: @CodeSpirit Why do you say **Plotly.animate** calls **update**?

Comment: @PintoDoido I didnt. Read carefully.

Comment: @CodeSpirit Sorry, indeed the function **update** calls **Plotly.animate**. I used this code structure because it is the one used in https://plot.ly/javascript/animations/#animating-many-frames-quickly . Do you know any way of making the animation smooth?

Comment: Heres where I have to quit. It was just a guess but it seems that Plotly handles animation state internally. I have no experience in Plotly so im sorry I cant help you further.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Plotly.redraw` or `Plotly.restyle`  to prevent clearing the frame.

```js
var rho = [];
for (var n = 0; n < 100; n++) {
  rho[n] = [];
  for (var l = 0; l < 100; l++) {
    rho[n][l] = n * l;
  }
}

var dummy = 1;

var data = [{
  z: rho,
  type: 'heatmap'
}];

function compute() {
  dummy++;
  for (n = 0; n < 100; n++) {
    for (l = 0; l < 100; l++) {
      data[0].z[n][l] = Math.sin(0.3 * (n * l - 0.05) + dummy);
    }
  }
}

Plotly.newPlot('graph', data);

function update() {
    compute();
    rho = data[0].z;
    let myDiv = document.getElementById("graph");

    myDiv.data.z = rho
    Plotly.redraw(myDiv);

    // Plotly.restyle(myDiv, 'z', [rho]);
}

setInterval(function () {
    update()
}, 200.0);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph" style="position: relative; width: 600px; height: 500px;"></div>
```